# Typescript: share types between a function params and an object properties

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for a way to share the types between a function params and an object properties.

Let me example this for you:

```js
const f = (param1: string, param2: number, param3: boolean): any => null
const n = (obj: Array<keys and types of every f function param>): any => null
```

So I can call the `n` function in this way:

```js
n([
  { param1: "a", param2: 1, param3: true },
  { param1: "b", param2: 2, param3: false },
])
```

I need to synchronize the params of the function `f` with the properties of the object `obj`.

`Parameters<typeof f>` is close but this returns the type `[string, number, boolean]` but I need `{ param1: string, param2: number, param3: boolean }` key-value based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try other way around - type the object first, and then type your function based on the object type:

```
type T = {param1: string, param2: number, param3: boolean}

const f = (param1: T['param1'], param2: T['param2'], param3: T['param3']): any => null

const n = (obj: T[]): any => null
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydaiodreUAAXlAAG8CI4GIgAIz5K6oSicZj8BlkJkAJjZnHYiGk3x5jMQAGY2cD4C1OABfRTkoiUmn0yWs9mc7nzSWC-oisVkCV86Wy%20DyjxK4IITiCGipGkACl5TO1OAA2gByd0sn0AXTNArZ3r9BqDIYt3l9-qlQYAlGyzHhqQA%20I3QaB2xqO-rU0Au%20DSABWYa9geTYk4aapmeF2eCyRdPoUjp9vH5vClieKOGaHjIXkQ8D6DGB7BoXzcZmY7AYzEg-Fg0HUiQn8D0Ii8ACIAKKrJkLfS7pLY3fgByoH3CABykAku6CKgA8l8yO9BMutJAjqhHAUVxpDTJxRx0YYsH0FAEEQaFhEuGcJDHaIRAMDhsQWJhWA4HgghKIA)